# Visual Basic 6 and real text format

Tags: vb6, rtf

I have a VB6 system (about to be rewritten in VB.NET) that builds contract documents using text passages held in rtf format.

Via the system I make decisions from information incorporated in these text passages and piece together the correct passages that are necessary for the specific case.

Part of the system is to position the "called in" text passages correctly based on the tabs and indents in the calling text passages.  This means that my system identifies the tab and indent points and resets them as is required.

This system has been successfully in operation since early 1980's and it is only now that two clients have requested to upgrades to MS Word 2010 and MS Word 2016 that my build is going haywire.

I assume this is to do with a change to the RTF codes and, if so, I need to either (a) rebuild my document processing module which is a major task, or (b) have a method of keeping the conversion to RTF in MS Word to the levels of MS Word 2003 or earlier even though the MS Word 2010 and/or MS Word 2016 will be loaded and operative on the users desktops.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated
Thanks
Mac

Comment: It seems that the question says: I produce a RTF file which is being interpreted different way in recent versions of MS-Word and I am looking for some "hack" to persuade MS-Word to process it the old way. In that case the question should have different tags and be asked on different forum (superuser).

Comment: I think you should add more specific examples of what the code is doing, and what is going wrong